# Group multiple sprites in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to add 4 sprites to a view, every sprite in another corner of an imaginary square and than rotate all sprites around center. What is the best way to complete this task?

I know how to rotate every single sprite, but maybe there is a way to group multiple sprites like putting them inside a container?

[How the result should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8kXq.png)

Comment: Just put SKSpriteNodes inside SKNode and rotate that SKNode

Comment: @Whirlwind suggestion should work. Have you tried?

Comment: @Whirlwind's suggestion depends on how you want the sprites to rotate. If you are looking for the sprites to stay in an up direction while you rotate around the circle, then you will need to apply some more math to correct the issue, but if you want the sprite to rotate with the square,  then do what Whirlwind suggests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my working code.

```
import SpriteKit

let player = SKNode()
let playerTopLeft = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.yellowColor(), size: CGSizeMake(20, 20))
let playerTopRight = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.yellowColor(), size: CGSizeMake(20, 20))
let playerBottomRight = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.yellowColor(), size: CGSizeMake(20, 20))
let playerBottomLeft = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.yellowColor(), size: CGSizeMake(20, 20))

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()

        player.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        addChild(player)

        playerTopLeft.position = CGPoint(x:-40, y:-40)
        player.addChild(playerTopLeft)

        playerTopRight.position = CGPoint(x:40, y:-40)
        player.addChild(playerTopRight)

        playerBottomRight.position = CGPoint(x:40, y:40)
        player.addChild(playerBottomRight)

        playerBottomLeft.position = CGPoint(x:-40, y:40)
        player.addChild(playerBottomLeft)

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches {

            let rotate = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(-M_PI_2), duration:1)
            player.runAction(rotate)

        }
    }
}
```